# Magento categories and sub-categories in side bar

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I need to display categories and sub-categories in left side or right side navigation and also display categories in two levels in Magento. Please advise me.....

For example:

```
categories
    ----sub1
        ---sub2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add category navigation in left side bar -

create new file "categorymenu.phtml" in your theme at - **template\catalog\navigation\categorymenu.phtml**

Put the following code in it -

```
<div class="block block-category">
 <div class="inside-box">
 <div class="block-title block-category-title"><h2><?php echo $this->__('Categories') ?></h2></div>
 <div class="block-category-navigation">
 <ul id="category-nav"> 
 <?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>  
 <?php if($_category->name!=""):  ?>    
 <li><?php echo $this->drawItem($_category) ?></li> 
 <?php endif?>  
 <?php endforeach ?>    
 </ul>  
 </div> 
 </div> 
</div>
```

then call this in the catalog.xml file located in the theme folder -

theme\layout\catalog.xml. it looks like :

```
<reference name="left">

<block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.categorymenu" after="top.search" template="catalog/navigation/categorymenu.phtml"/> <-- this is new block added by us -->

 <block type="core/template" name="left.permanent.callout" template="callouts/left_col.phtml">

...
...
</reference>
```

Answer (score 1):

go to layout xml folder ...

> /app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/catalog.xml

open catalog.xml and paste it...

```
    <reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" template="catalog/navigation/left_nav.phtml" />
</reference>
```

further modified the .phtml file..

```
<?php
$obj = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
$store_cats = $obj->getStoreCategories();
$current_cat    = $obj->getCurrentCategory();
$current_cat    = (is_object($current_cat) ? $current_cat->getName() : '');

foreach ($store_cats as $cat) {
    if ($cat->getName() == $current_cat) {
        echo '<li class="current"><a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($cat).'">'.$cat->getName()."</a>\n<ul>\n";
        foreach ($obj->getCurrentChildCategories() as $subcat) {
            echo '<li><a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($subcat).'">'.$subcat->getName()."</a></li>\n";
        }
        echo "</ul>\n</li>\n";
    } else {
        echo '<li><a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($cat).'">'.$cat->getName()."</a></li>\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Now refresh the cache and re-index process....

Comment: what about my answer.....is it correct or not?

Comment: This one worked for me